# Vaadin set combo box value after it has been filled

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin, vaadin7

My instance of the combo box is created globally, It gets filled with, lets say a list of companies while the value is an ID. After I load a File, I want to check that I have that value in the combo box and then select it programmatically.

```
class cComboBoxFun extends UI implements ClickListener
{
  ComboBox cb_company;
  List<cCustomer> ListCust;

  //default constructor and server conf not really relevant

  @Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) 
{
      //Lets assume the list has been filled already
      cb_company = new ComboBox("Company");

      for(cCustomer cust : ListCust)
      {
        cb_company.addItem(cust.mgetId);
        cb_company.setItemcaption(cust.mgetId, cust.mgetName);
      }


    }

    class cCustomer()
    {
      private String name;
      private String Id;

      public String GetName() 
      {
        return this.name
      }

       // Same for id

    }
```

I tried checking the value is there and setting it but nothing happens. I looked up but couldn't find an answer

```
if(cb_company.getItemCaption(value) != null)
    cb_company.set(value);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that your `ComboBox` uses single select mode, you can select a given item programatically with

```
cb_company.select(value)
```

where `value` points to `cCustomer.Id`. So the code may look as follows:

```
cb_company = new ComboBox("Company");

for(cCustomer cust : ListCust)
{
    cb_company.addItem(cust.mgetId);
    cb_company.setItemcaption(cust.mgetId, cuts.mgetName);
}

//select the first item from the container
cb_company.select(ListCust.get(0));
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to set with the name ...
smh

Comment: not working for me, even when i fixed the id to 10 for example